# what's the gradle alternative to a fat JAR?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, classpath, build.gradle

If transitive libs aren't [packaged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34242899/262852) with the `JAR` task:

```
By default, jar task in gradle builds an executable jar file from your project source files. It will not contain any transitive libs that are needed for your program.
```

To the contrary, Netbeans **does** package `JAR` dependencies or transitive libs.  Rather than a fat `JAR` how does gradle include libs?

```
plugins {
    id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version '1.8' 
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}


mainClassName = 'net.bounceme.dur.mbaas.json.Main'


buildScan {
    licenseAgreementUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
    licenseAgree = 'yes'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}


jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'net.bounceme.dur.mbaas.json.Main'
    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    runtime group: 'com.google.firebase', name: 'firebase-admin', version: '5.2.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar') 
}
```

in relation to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44965650/262852) question:  what's the "way" to package libs with the `JAR` task which doesn't result in a "fat `JAR`"?

Comment: http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/

Comment: Are you really asking [how to create a fat jar using Gradle](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+create+a+fat+jar+using+Gradle&oq=how+to+create+a+fat+jar+using+Gradle&aqs=chrome..69i57.133j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)? Because the answer to "what's the gradle alternative to a fat JAR?" is "don't create a fat jar".

Comment: all the files in this fat JAR:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/25048768/   instead of including them **inside** the fat JAR I want a non-fat JAR.  But, I also want those JAR's on the classpath.  Not just on the classpath, but actually in their own directory.  I don't know the terminology, but like this:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Answer (score 2):

When using the application plugin, all libraries used by the application (own jar or transitive libraries) are put in a libs folder when packaged as an app. then these libs are referenced in the shell or batch script as classpath when launching the app.

The easiest way to create a fatjar in gradle, is to use the shadow plugin available via the plugin portal. see https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.johnrengelman.plugin-shadow for details

Comment: I must be asking the question wrong.  How do I create a NON fat jar and libs?